# Entity Framework performance optimization

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

Yet another EF performance question... I have an XLSX file which I'm processing and inserting the records from it to the database. The problem is that the XLSX data is un-normalized and I have to normalize it within the DB which means to do a lot of DB calls while processing. So I have a main for loop which goes through the XLSX and then checks within the DB if records already exist. It goes something like this:

```
List<MainEntity> mainEntities= new List<MainEntity>();

for (int xlsIowIterator = 2; xlsIterator <= 300; xlsIterator++) {
    MainEntity mainEntity = new MainEntity();
    mainEntity.data1 = XLSData1;
    mainEntity.data2 = XLSData2;
    RelatedEntity relatedEntity= repository.FindSingleBy(x => x.MyId.Equals(data));
    mainEntity.RelatedEntity = relatedEntity;
    mainEntities.Add(mainEntity);
}
mainEntities.ForEach(s => context.MainEntities.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Saving the changes is fine - the problem is with that call from the repository to the database within the for loop:

```
RelatedEntity relatedEntity= repository.FindSingleBy(x => x.MyId.Equals(data));
```

For each record form the XLSX file, I'm querying the database and it kills the performance. 300 records take about a minute to process and I have other related entities that I need to retrieve and attach to the main entity... Is there any way to optimize this approach or I should just give up on Entity Framework and move this functionality to a stored procedure on the database side? I really would like to keep all logic in the business layer, but I will be processing thousands of records and waiting more than 10 minutes for a page to finish is ridiculous. I'm thinking of just Bulk Loading the entire Excel file in a table and then writing a stored procedure to process it...
Any help/insights are highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Not so much about optimizing EF.  You need to write it differently.  Go get all the records first.

Comment: gather all the ids in memory, then get the entries in a single transaction